# HashSet NullPointerException error during iterating

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, iterator, hashset

This is my main code:

```
package onlineTest;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<TrueFalseQuestion> newList = new  HashSet<TrueFalseQuestion>(); 
    newList.add(new TrueFalseQuestion(1, 2, "sms", 4, true));
    newList.add(new TrueFalseQuestion(2, 3, "erw", 5, false));
    newList.add(new TrueFalseQuestion(3, 4, "Gray", 6, true));

    Iterator<TrueFalseQuestion> iterator = newList.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(iterator.next());
      System.out.println(iterator.next().getPoints());
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my TrueFalseQuestion class:

```
public class TrueFalseQuestion {

  public int examId;
  public int questionNum;
  public String text;
  public double points;
  public boolean answer;

  public TrueFalseQuestion(int examId, int questionNum, String text,
        double points, boolean answer) {
    this.examId = examId;
    this.questionNum = questionNum;
    this.text = text;
    this.points = points;
    this.answer = answer;
  }

  public int getExamId() {
    return examId;
  }

  public int getQuestionNum() {
    return questionNum;
  }

  public String getQuestionText() {
    return text;
  }

  public boolean getAnswer() {
    return answer;
  }

  public double getPoints() {
    return points;
  }
}
```

When I run my code, it is able to go through the first iteration and print the points out fine, but then it gives a `NullPointerException` for the second iteration. The line that cases the error is:

```
System.out.println(iterator.next().getPoints());
```

I have no idea what the problem is. I assumed that iterator.next() was the current `TrueFalseQuestion` object and that each iteration, I could use `getPoints()`.

Comment: Are you sure its throwing from `System.out.println(iterator.next().getPoints());` line ? what `System.out.println(iterator.next());` printing ?

Comment: Are you sure it's a `NullPointerException` you're getting? Not a `NoSuchElementException`?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're calling `itertor.next()` twice inside your loop for every `iterator.hasNext()`.

You should do:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  TrueFalseQuestion trueFalseQuestion = iterator.next();
  System.out.println(trueFalseQuestion);
  System.out.println(trueFalseQuestion.getPoints());
}
```

What happens in you're first iteration is that when you call:

```
System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

The first `TrueFalseQuestion` gets printed, however in the very next statement, when you do:

```
System.out.println(iterator.next().getPoints());
```

You're unknowingly printing the `points` of the second `TrueFalseQuestion`.

So, in you're second iteration, again when you do:

```
System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

The third `TrueFalseQuestion` is printed, and finally, on the very next line when you do:

```
System.out.println(iterator.next().getPoints());
```

There isn't a fourth `TrueFalseQuestion` and you get a `NullPointerException` because you are calling `getPoints()` on a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

array value in your program can not found your array so it display null pointer exception 
 notice that your array index start with 0